# Regular Expression VBA : find particular set of data

Tags: regex, vba, excel

I've encountered an issue with my macro.
I'm trying to find in a string, elements beginning with FP 608 or TM 608.

The string I try to extract always begins with FP or TM. The elements after are numbers, 3 or 4 numbers (100 or 1000). they can also have 2 decimals (100.10 or 1000.10).

For instance it should extract :

- ABCDF FP 573,83 ABDFEG HIJ KLM 0124" : Extract : 573,83
- ABCFED ERD 536,98 [...] = no extraction
- TM 123,12 ABCDD EFGHIJ KLM : Extract TM 123,12
- FP 100 : Extract : FP 100

This seems to work but it's inefficient :

```
Function GetRealCost(MyRange As Variant)

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.DisplayStatusBar = False

    Dim regEx As Object
    Set regEx = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
    Dim strPattern As String
    Dim strInput As String
    Dim strOutput As Object

    strPattern = "\b(TM )([0-9]{3,4})(,[0-9]{1,2}\b)"

    With regEx
        .Global = True
        .MultiLine = True
        .IgnoreCase = False
        .Pattern = strPattern
    End With

        strInput = MyRange

        If regEx.test(strInput) Then
            regEx.Pattern = "(\b[0-9]{3,4})(,[0-9]{1,2}\b)"
            Set strOutput = regEx.Execute(MyRange)
            GetRealCost = regEx.Execute(strInput)(0)
        Else
            strPattern = "\b(TM )([0-9]{3,4}\b)"
            regEx.Pattern = strPattern
                If regEx.test(strInput) Then
                    regEx.Pattern = "(\b[0-9]{3,4}\b)"
                    Set strOutput = regEx.Execute(MyRange)
                    GetRealCost = regEx.Execute(strInput)(0)
                        Else
                            strPattern = "\b(FP )([0-9]{3,4})(,[0-9]{1,2}\b)"
                            regEx.Pattern = strPattern
                                If regEx.test(strInput) Then
                                regEx.Pattern = "(\b[0-9]{3,4})(,[0-9]{1,2}\b)"
                                Set strOutput = regEx.Execute(MyRange)
                                GetRealCost = regEx.Execute(strInput)(0)
                                        Else
                                strPattern = "\b(FP )([0-9]{3,4}\b)"
                                regEx.Pattern = strPattern
                                    If regEx.test(strInput) Then
                                        regEx.Pattern = "(\b[0-9]{3,4}\b)"
                                        Set strOutput = regEx.Execute(MyRange)
                                        GetRealCost = regEx.Execute(strInput)(0)
                                            Else
                                        GetRealCost = ""
                                    End If
                    End If
                End If
        End If

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Function
```

Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

The inefficieny is mainly due to applying and testing many regular expressions, which all can be merged into a single one. Also, code speed can be improved by creating and setting that `RegExp` object only once, because creating and setting it for each cell using the formula may turn really ineffective.

Finally, I dont believe that it's a good idea to disable/enable the screen updating and other stuff inside a **UDF**, because that will apply once for each individually calculated cell, which is counter-intuitive, and it will have no effect actually because UDF's are not allowed to change the state of the application apart from computing a result.

You might try this UDF instead:

```
Function GetRealCost(strInput As String) As String
  Static reg As Object
  If reg Is Nothing Then
    Set reg = CreateObject("vbscript.RegExp")
    reg.Global = True
    reg.MultiLine = True
    reg.IgnoreCase = False
    reg.Pattern = "\b((FP )|(TM ))\d{3,4}(,\d{1,2})?\b"
  End If

  Dim matches As Object: Set matches = reg.Execute(strInput)
  If matches.count <> 0 Then GetRealCost = Mid(matches(0), 4)
End Function
```

Comment: Thank you ! I'll try it and let you know :) The ScreenUpdating thing was a mistake, I didn't see it... I set both to false and the performance have increase a lot (up to 4 time more efficient).